# Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS - unable to configure Wacom Intuos Comic (CTH-490)

Tags: wacom, graphics-tablet

I plugged in my Wacom Intuos Comic and Ubuntu detected it (I guess...). At least I could use the tablet as "mouse" and could draw with it in Gimp even with the sensitivity of the pen (means the harder I push the thicker the lines get), after I activated them in Gimp.

BUT: That's all. I can't configure the buttons on the pen or tablet, which I used to zoom in/out or undo/redo. In the settings I only see that there's no tablet connected.

Here's the settings menu:

[image: settings menu]

(yup, I'm german)

And here a terminal which shows the tablet, pen and touch-surface:

[image: terminal]

Answer (score 0):

See this bug: https://sourceforge.net/p/linuxwacom/bugs/320/ and its associated launchpad issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1575887